# Using unique non clustered index with unique clustered index

Tags: sql-server, nonclustered-index

Would there be any scenario where it would make sense to create a unique non clustered index that includes a column that is contained in a unique clustered index?

In other words, if I have a Products table with a unique clustered index on the ProductID column. Would there be an acceptable scenario where I would need to create a unique non clustered index that includes the ProductID column in addition to a couple of other columns, or, would the mere inclusion of the unique ProductID column make creating the non clustered index unique irrelevant?

Comment: If you have overlapping candidate keys the table is not in BCNF.

Comment: @MartinSmith: index != key

Comment: @mustaccio - Two unique indexes means two candidate keys.

Comment: That is true of course but generally indexes (including unique ones) exist also for other reasons, don't they.

Comment: @mustaccio - True. I can think of a couple of situations where you might want this but there is no overlapping candidate key actually. A much narrower NCI on the same column as the CI might be justified in some cases. Also supertype/subtype pattern needs a redundant unique constraint for the FK.

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks Martin, could you elaborate the couple of situations where you might want this as this is the essence of the question.

Comment: From the fact you mention *clustered index*, I assume this is for `sql-server` - added tag to indicate as much

Comment: Do you mean include literally, as in the `INCLUDE()` clause, or do you mean as part of the key?

Comment: It also might help if we have some more context - what is the second index for - is it to enforce uniqueness, or to aid in some query or queries? What are those queries? Is ProductID the leading column?

Comment: @Aaron - I mean as part of the key, not the INCLUDE(). Not to enforce uniqueness, simply to aid in queries. ProductID is the leading column.

Comment: @Aaron - Unique non-clustered index exists containing the ProductID column as well as two other columns, however from what I can see there is no need to have created the non-clustered index as unique because by the very existence of the ProductID column, the combination of the 3 columns is unique. So wanting to find out would there be a reason for doing so other than simply having a unique combination.

Comment: @Nico It's possible that - in cases where the skinnier index satisfies the query - the fact that it's unique could be information that helps SQL Server (even though, theoretically, it can deduce that). I'm really not sure if it would make a difference for you, but at the same time I see no *harm* in specifying `UNIQUE`.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. Would there be a performance benefit in making the non-clustered index unique or is it one of those "it depends" questions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes having a column in multiple unique keys is sometimes perfectly reasonable.  In the case that you gave above I'm not sure I would bother since the ProductId key is unique regardless.  But let's say that you have a product table like this:

```
ProductVendor  PK
ProductCode  PK
ProductDescription
.....
```

In this particular case the `ProductVendor` and `ProductCode` are together unique and are your primary key and clustered index.  However there is an additional business rule that `ProductDescription` must also be unique by `ProductVendor`.  In this case you could create a non-clustered index on `ProductVendor, ProductDescription`.

Comment: Aha, we are narrowing down the answer. So the question is would there be any reason why one would want to make the non-clustered index on ProductVendor, ProductDescription unique?

Comment: It could simply be a business rule that vendor cannot name more than one product the same thing.  They also cannot have the same code for two different products.  Because you are storing multiple vendors the ProductVendor column will have to be in both unique indexes.

Comment: Thanks for your input. This has helped me to clarify in my mind that the business rule may require a unique combination of columns even though one or more of the columns in itself may be unique. Thanks for your help.